# Jquery slider first item title issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, caroufredsel

I'm working on a Jquery slider (caroufredsel), where I want some elements to be shown above the slider itself, so outside of the wrapper. I managed to get this working, unfortunatly not for the first slide ! I'm trying to figure this thing out now for a few days and come to the conclusion I've run out of ideas.

My javascript is as follows:

```
function showTitle( item ) {
                           $('.pstitle').html(item.attr('data-title'));
                           }
                          function showSlogan( item ) {                               
                           $('.psslogan').html(item.attr('data-slogan'));
                           }

                           $(function() {

                             $('#pscontainer').carouFredSel({

                                circular:false,
                                items: {
                                  visible: 1,
                                  start: false
                                },

                                width: '100%',
                                auto: false,
                                prev: '#psprev',
                                next: '#psnext',
                                scroll : {

                                   onAfter: function( data ) {
                                   showTitle( data.items.visible.eq(0) );
                                   showSlogan( data.items.visible.eq(0) );

                                   }                             
                                },

                                pagination: {
                                   container: '#pager',
                                   anchorBuilder: function( nr ) {
                                      var title = $(this).find( "div.websitenaam" ).text();
                                      return'<li><a href="#">' + title + '</span></a></li>';
                                   }

                                }

                             });   

                           });
```

And my HTML (one slide, for working example with multiple slides see my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X3k6b/1/):

```
 <!-- portfolio slider handles -->
            <div class="pshandles">
                <span id="psprev"></span>
                <div class="pstitlecontainer">
                    <span class="pstitle"></span>
                    <span class="psslogan"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- einde next/prev en title -->
                <span id="psnext"></span>                
            <!-- einde portfolio slider handles -->
            </div>

            <!-- portfolio slider container -->
            <div id="pscontainer">


                <!-- portfolio item -->
                <div class="pslide" data-title="Sitename 1" data-slogan="Site slogan 1" id="site1">

                    <div class="psimg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="psinfo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="psstats">
                        <div class="extra">
                            <div class="websitenaam">Sitename 1</div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- einde portfolio item -->
                </div>

<!-- end portfolio slider container -->   
            </div>

            <!-- sites menu -->
            <div class="sitesmenu">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="pager">
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <!-- end sites menu -->
            </div>
```

What I try to do, is showing the values of the .psslide DIV data-title and data-slogan attributes inside the .pstitle and .psslogan DIVs.

I've got this working, only the FIRST slide won't display the values. When clicking back and forth, it will show up properly. I guess this has something to do with the onAfter function, but I really can't figure out how I can get this right!

See my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X3k6b/1/ for a "working" example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

regards,

Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the onCreate property to your $('#pscontainer').carouFredSel. This will solve your problem.

```
onCreate: function(data){
  showTitle( $(data.items[0]) );
  showSlogan( $(data.items[0]) );
  },
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/dzffV/

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! I've tried the onCreate already, but always used data.items.visible.eq(0) instead of data.items[0]. Cheers and thanks again Raimond!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/X3k6b/3/

```
var selected_value = $("#pager").find('.selected').text();
$('.pstitle').html(selected_value);
$('.psslogan').html(selected_value);
```

Hi Mr.Jeroen I am not aware of slider but through the above jQuery code i can show the title on the first time. please try this. Let me know your comments.

Comment: Thank you Vinothini, this indeed works! I've used Raimonds solution since it uses the slider's property. Thanks for your effords!